# The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'txt';
$config['max_size'] = '10000';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('datafile')){
    print_r($this->upload->display_errors());  
}else{
      // rest of work
 }
```

Everything is ok but when it try to upload a text file containing `char` starting new line ( example: `charlie@mail.com` ), it shows this error:
`The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

Does it conflict with any `xss` filter? Maybe not, cause i have tried with remove xss filter function from `system/libraries/Upload.php`

But`var_dump($_FILES);` shows that it is correct `mime` type file.

Codeigniter version `3.0.3`

**Addition:**

when it gets global file type setting:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

It works. But this is not the solution. Does it somehow conflict with `mime` type filtering ?

Comment: What is shown as _correct file type_ for `charlie@mail.com`?

Comment: Shown `text/plain`

Comment: Is that exact name of text file?

Comment: no, this is file type shown while dump the result. 
filename is with anything.txt

Comment: Is file named `charlie.txt`, for example, being uploaded?

Comment: no. 
Actually  filename is not the problem. I have used several text file. with or without `char` starting new line. Only `char` containing files get the problem.

Comment: So file name is not the problem, then? Maybe you didn't mention/show but have some code that reads file content?

Comment: No, just using CI default built in upload library. I think it can be a bug cause in older version like `2.+` there is no such problem. I have tested. 
I am doing test with several versions, I will give the result in question sooner.

Comment: You should provide full code letting us to try to reproduce the same error. Otherwise it is not easy to debug/conclude what is going on there.

Comment: ok, code updated.

Comment: Comment out `$this->upload->initialize($config);` line. When you load library with constructor array, you don't need to initialize it again.

Comment: Right, i did it too. 
But same matter. 
So i brought again to confirm initialize. Unnecessary, but checking each way.

Comment: If you use `initialize()` method, load library with no array parameter.

Comment: @Tpojka , it is ok. it is just overwrite initialize. I mean, no conflict here. Just execution time delay. 
Ok, updated again.

Comment: From code you offered that behaviour can't be reproduced. It is basic upload example code from docs that works. Bug is somewhere else in code. What kind of server/environment you are using?

Comment: localhost (wamp) and web server ( centos )  both.
btw, if you want to reproduce, i will request you to use CI version 3+ and try to upload a .txt file containing `char` starting new line with very basic upload function.

Comment: @Narf I reproduced the same error. Something to investigate?

Comment: @Tpojka, Opened an issue in github. If you can detect the reason of the problem you may contribute there too: 
`https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5256`

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to make some conclusion in this very moment. I am using virtual Ubuntu though. This is very strange behaviour to me. I also tried to upload _testFile.txt_ example file with content of `#!/bin/bash` and I was refused. I think it could be something with Linux.

Comment: Good finding. It's not only with text but also with image file too. I mean editing inside of img file with "char" word
But strange matter is excel file is ok with it. So if it would be a linux problem i think all types of uploading would be blocked. 
Moreover, There is no problem with older version. 
So i think it is problem within CI

Answer (score 0):

As already described in [GitHub issues](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5256), you can solve this.
Following two topics that could be related to this ([GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/moodle-local_o365/issues/3), [PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53035)), I wasn't able to understand real nature of this behaviour. Although I came to two possible solutions:

1.) extend mime type for txt extension in [**APPPATH . 'config/mimes.php'**](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/mimes.php#L95)

```
'txt'   =>      ['text/plain', 'text/x-c'],
```

2.) to use [vanilla PHP upload code](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-384) that allows me to upload such a file without updating default mimes.php file.

Comment: You might be missed my last line: 
`It works. But this is not the solution. Does it somehow conflict with mime type filtering ? `
I want to know the reason for that.I read narfbg's comment there. This is not that simple i think. 
I will update some testing sooner

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for the problem**:

[narfbg](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5256) detected the mime-type return for the file containing `char` starting new line is different than normal text file mime type.

`char` is a C variable type. So when uploading the file, server return it is a `text/x-c` mime type file. It also conflicts with `float` and `double`. Those are also C variable types.

**Solution:**

I have found two solutions:

**1)** Upload file with no mime detection:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

Then check file extension. If it is `.txt` file, then process:

```
$file_extension = $uploadData['file_ext'];
if($file_extension == ".txt"){
   //process
 }
```

**2)** add `'text/x-c'` mime type in `application/config/mimes.php'` for `.txt` extension:

```
'txt' => array('text/plain', 'text/x-c')
```